# Icon placement relative to list items

Tags: css

When I show a hidden div that is stored inside an `<li>` tag the icons are pushing down to the bottom of the `<li>`. How can I prevent this?

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>Utah
   <ul>
      <li>Park City
         <ul>
             <li>Park Cat 1
                  <div><img class="portf_edit" /></div>
                  <div><img class="portf_archive" /></div>
                  <div><img class="portf_delete" /></div>
             </li>
             <li>Skiing
                  <div><img class="portf_edit" /></div>
                  <div><img class="portf_archive" /></div>
                  <div><img class="portf_delete" /></div>
             </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here's the li css:

```
li {
list-style-type:none;
vertical-align: top;
list-style-image: none;
left:0px;
text-align:left;
clear: both;
}
.portf_edit{
float:right;
position: relative;
right:50px;
display:block;
}
.portf_archive{
float:right;
position: relative;
right:-5px;
display:block;
}
.portf_delete{
float:right;
position: relative;
right: -60px;
display:block;
}
```

Here's a screen shot prior to expanding which shows the icons how I want them to line up:

[alt text http://www.redsandstech.com/css_layout_problem1.jpg](http://www.redsandstech.com/css_layout_problem1.jpg)

Here's the screen shot prior to expanding which shows where the icons are being pushed to:

[alt text http://www.redsandstech.com/css_layout_problem2.jpg](http://www.redsandstech.com/css_layout_problem2.jpg)

Comment: Might need to post a bit of code.

Comment: sorry, forgot to include...it's there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're right-floating the EDIT/ARCHIVE/DELETE buttons, specify them BEFORE the text.  Like this:

```
<li>
   <div><img class="edit" /></div>
   <div><img class="archive" /></div>
   <div><img class="delete" /></div>
   Park Cat 1
</li>
```

Also, you may need to specify a width on the LI; something like "100%".

Comment: I think the problem is more about the images shifting left rather than down, but this will be the next problem to surface.

Comment: This fixed it without having to add the width.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the `<li>` as tall as your images.

```
<li class="with-icons">Skiing
    <div><img class="portf_edit" /></div>
    <div><img class="portf_archive" /></div>
    <div><img class="portf_delete" /></div>
</li>
```

and

```
li .with-icons {
    height: 32px; // adjust according to your image size
}
```

You may be able to omit the `div` around each image, too.  Not sure they're necessary.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  the div's have some onclick events I took out for simplicity in reading the code.  The problem ended up being the order which I placed the divs.  Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: I had the right answer then I edited it away.  Always trust your gut!